# Why are my Terraria characters restricted from being certain colors?

Tags: terraria

One of my favorite hex colors is "Slate Gray": `2F4F4F` (or `47` `79` `79`).

I'm currently trying to make a character for the first time in Terraria, and I've found that  the 'blue' value for color is prevented from being very low; further experimentation indicates that the more likely case is that the sum of the RGB values must be >= 254.

This makes a heap of hex colors unobtainable.

Why does Terraria limit the character color pallete like this? Are there any workarounds?

I'm aware that clothing color will become largely meaningless as soon as I get some armor, but it's the principal of the thing that irks me.

Comment: I like the fact that you have a favourite hex colour.

Comment: I believe the rule was that RGB must add up to about ~257.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe the idea is to prevent people from making characters that are too dark.  If you could turn yourself too dark you'd be invisible in some areas of the game, which would give you an unfair advantage in PvP.

There's a thread about this on the [official Terraria forums](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/why-no-black.13532/).

Comment: That was a conclusion I came to as well. Is there any way around this for single-player mode?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe so.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: There are two ways of implementing this. One is to remove the conditions from the executable, the other is to adjust the configuration of your character. The first could be achieved with Reflector and I don't know how the second is stored but it could be easy to discover with a hex editor. Kind of like storing `(59,99,99)` and looking if `3B6363` or `63633B` can be found...

Comment: @TomWijsman You can't actually modify executables with Reflector, other than recompiling. You need a separate plugin for that.

Answer (score 7):

Even as far as workarounds go, I expect the best you'll be able to do is to scale your color up.  `3B6363` (59, 99, 99) is the closest color which Terraria will accept, which is at least still nicely dark.

Answer (score 7):

Terraria InvEdit allows all colors to be accessed, you can also change your name.

Comment: +1 as this is the only real solution. the others are just explanation why it isn’t possible from within the game.

Comment: @Flying Sheep - though there's something to be said about the possible ramifications of using 3rd party tools to get around in-built limitations.

Comment: and what would that be?

Answer (score 2):

In one of the more recent versions of Terraria (unfortunately my Google-fu is failing to help me find which specific version number), the system of setting clothes color by number is gone. Instead, the player is given a color slider, which goes from pitch black to stark white, with all the colors in between. There do not seem to be any limits to the colors you can choose anymore. The same color slider can be accessed in-game by using a [Dresser](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dresser), which allows you to change your clothes colors anytime you like.